# Rails doesn't load ru.yml without patching of application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I've created ru.yml, but Rails doesn't load it. Only loads if I add:

`config.i18n.load_path = Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.yml')]`

to application.rb. Why rails doesn't load ru.yml automatically?

P.S. Default locale is 'ru':

`config.i18n.default_locale = :ru`

Rails version is 4.1.6.

Comment: Have you restarted rails after adding `ru.yml`?

Comment: i assume you forget `.to_s` at your load path, as in example `Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]` from Rails comments in `config/application.rb`

Comment: Зелёный, it works without .to_s too. The problem is that it doesn't work without such lines at all.